# java.lang.Error am i missing something in the code?

Tags: java, loops, ide

This is just a simple query if anyone knows why I am facing this error I would appreciate the help.

The problem is simple java if else if else loop problem .

so I tried to make syntax as correct as possible.
The code here below is the one I am executing.

```
 public class ifelseloop {
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        //  int a = 20;
        //  int b = 20;
    
        String city = "Delhi";
    
        if (city == "madras") {
            System.out.println("the city is not delhi its madras");
        }else if(city == "chennai") {
            System.out.println("the city is not delhi its chennai");
        }else if(city == "bartar") {
            System.out.println("the city is bartar");
        }else {
            System.out.println(city);
        }
    }
}
```

and the error that I am getting is this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at ifelseloop.main(ifelseloop.java:2)
```

Comment: `if else` statement is not a loop.

Comment: That code compiles for me -- perhaps you haven't recompiled since you fixed it? Also, you can't compare strings using `==`, use `.equals()`

Comment: Compiles and runs successfully for me, have you pasted the contact code?
Apart from the issues pointed above i don't see any issue.

Comment: Works for me, did you miss the closing "}" for the ifelseloop's  class body?

Comment: @Vinod that code had some issue but I rewrote the code again and this time it worked fine. thanks for helping and giving your valuable opnion.

Comment: HI Everybody thanks for giving your valuable opinions. so I wrote the code once again in cleaner format and everything worked fine.